# Passar propriedade para o component Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, app

Bom dia,

Poderiam me ajudar a passar um propriedade para um component do angular.

Estou com uma page e chamo component

```
<app-top-bar name="Agendamento" ></app-top-bar>
```

Como já utilizei react é mais ou menos dessa forma que passamos propriedade nele.

Agora no meu componente eu gostaria de passar dentro desse component do Ionic.

```
<ion-title>{{name}}</ion-title>
```

Bom estou iniciando no angular, desculpa ter pouco informação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso, você precisará usar o @Input em seu componente filho para acessar a variável "name", a qual está sendo passada no seu pai.

Por exemplo, vamos considerar que temos um componente `users`:

```
<app-users [users]="users"></app-users>
```

Estamos passando os valores da variável users para ele, e no nosso componente `Users`, fazemos da seguinte forma:

```
// users.component.ts  
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-users',
    templateUrl: './users.component.html',
})

export class TeamModalComponent {
    // Com este @Input(), dizemos que
    // esta variável está associada ao
    // componente pai, MainComponent
    @Input() users;
}
```

[Neste artigo do meu blog](https://backefront.com.br/compartilhando-variaveis-angular/), escrevi justamente sobre isso, caso queira dar uma lida por lá!

Answer (score 0):

Podes utilizar tanto da forma de **@Input**, que já explicaram, como na forma de **ng-content**.

**Chamada do componente:**

```
<app-top-bar>Agendamento</app-top-bar>
```

**Dentro do componente:**

```
<ion-title>
     <ng-content></ng-content>
</ion-title>
```

No teu caso é melhor o @Input, mas quando utilizar o ng-content?
Quando você tiver blocos de HTML que precisam ser passados para um componente. Geralmente é utilizado na montagem de templates.